# Appcelerator - ios push notification bug

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm working with push notifications using Appcelerator.

Is it possible that this important bug
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-18282
is still open?

The bug occurs when an ios app receive a push notification. If the app is closed, nothing is fired.

On iOS, there is no way to handle a push notification is it arrives when the app is closed.
I'm so disappointed. Push notifications are important in modern apps! And in Appcelerator don't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all that bug is still open because it can never be solved and in fact it is a limitation from Apple itself or even it is the limitation of every mobile OS.

[Apple Push Notification Limitation](http://bluetubeinc.com/blog/2013/6/limitations-of-apple-push-notifications)

Read the above link for more details and you will have your all doubts cleared about Push notifications. Currently Titanium support best Push Notification handling when compared to cross-platform frameworks.

After reading above post, if you have any other doubts, then we are happy to help!

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my angry question :)

Comment: If you have got your queries answered by my post, then please mark this answer as accepted to help other users with similar queries.